# Unity3d Nontraditional snake game collision with rigid bodies

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision

I am working on a twist to the classic nokia snake game with Unity3D. We decided we wanted to try and redo the way our snake works.

Videos here show a demo of what I have so far, with the new control setup
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4306843/Unity%202012-10-08%2010-11-05-44.avi
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4306843/Unity%202012-10-08%2017-51-40-42.avi

I am basically looking for a way to get this affect but collide with rigid bodies and self(or maybe just head).

code is based on info here.
http://processing.org/learning/topics/follow3.html

Any help or suggestions on how to get the snake to not penetrate through rigid bodies would be very much appreciated!

the bulk of the work is done here, Its called for each object in the chain.

```
void dragSegment(int i, float xin, float yin)
        {
            float dx = xin - x[i];
            float dy = yin - y[i];
            float angle1 = Mathf.Atan2(dy, dx);
            x[i] = xin - Mathf.Cos(angle1)*segLength;
            y[i] = yin - Mathf.Sin(angle1)*segLength;

            //set object pos
            obj[i].GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MovePosition(new Vector3(x[i],y[i],0));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution was actually really simple. I needed to get vector between dragobject and collider, normalize the vector and add it back to the x and y positions to get updated like normal.

Here is a the updated code,

```
void DragSegment(int i, float xin, float yin)
{
    if (obj[i].Hit)
    {
        Vector2 objV = new Vector2(x[i] - obj[i].Obj.GetComponent<Body ().hitObjectPos.x, y[i] - obj[i].Obj.GetComponent<Body>().hitObjectPos.y);
        objV = objV.normalized;

        x[i] += objV.x*1.2f;
        y[i] += objV.y*1.2f;

    }
    //Getting difference with last objects position
    float dx = xin - x[i];
    float dy = yin - y[i];
    angle1 = Mathf.Atan2(dy, dx);
    x[i] = xin - (Mathf.Cos(angle1) * segLength);
    y[i] = yin - (Mathf.Sin(angle1) * segLength);

    //simple gravity effect
    if (gravity == 1) y[i] += 0.1f;

    obj[i].Obj.transform.position = (new Vector3(x[i], y[i], 0));
}
```